# VBA Runtime Error 9: Subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, excel-2010

I have been trying to write a small piece of code to validate to confirm whether or not a date is included in an array. I have been able to scroll through the code until I reach the line `If lists(i) = TodaysDate Then` when the `lists(i)` show `subscript out of range`. I have searched through the Internet and I'm unable to resolve this issue.

My Macro reads as follows:

```
Sub size_an_array()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Range_of_Dates As Integer
    Dim TodaysDate As Variant, finish As String
    TodaysDate = Range("Sheet11!c2")
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet11").Activate
    lists = Range("Processed_Dates")

    Range_of_Dates = UBound(lists, 1) - LBound(lists, 1) + 1

     For c = 1 To UBound(lists, 1) ' First array dimension is rows.
         For R = 1 To UBound(lists, 2) ' Second array dimension is columns.
             Debug.Print lists(c, R)
         Next R
     Next c

     x = Range_of_Dates  'UBound(lists, 1)
     ReDim lists(x, 1)

     i = 1
     Do Until i = x
         If lists(i) = TodaysDate Then
             Exit Do
         End If
     Loop

     MsgBox "The date has not been found"

End Sub
```

I'm relatively new to `VBA` and I have been trying to use named ranges to pull in the array but I'm completely at my wits end in trying to solve this piece.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you have to compare values, so add ".Value" on both sides. Variable x is also not defined, so the error has to appear earlier

Answer (score 2):

You have ReDimmed the array `lists` from a one dimensioned array to a two dimensioned array and you are then trying to reference an element using only one dimension in the suspect line (below), which is causing your error.

`If lists(i) = TodaysDate Then`

For reference, `Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range` means you are referencing a non-existent array element.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying?

```
Sub size_an_array()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim TodaysDate As Variant, lists
    Dim bFound As Boolean

    '~~> Change SomeWorksheet to the relevant sheet
    TodaysDate = Sheets("SomeWorksheet").Range("c2")

    lists = Sheets("Sheet11").Range("Processed_Dates")

    i = 1
    Do Until i = UBound(lists)
        If lists(i, 1) = TodaysDate Then
            bFound = True
            Exit Do
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    If bFound = True Then
        MsgBox "The date has been found"
    Else
        MsgBox "The date has not been found"
    End If
End Sub
```

If I understand you correctly then it is much easier to use `.Find`. If you are interested then have a look at this [link](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/).

Comment: Thanks for this, I have also looked at your article on .Find and will try this later. I have tried executing the code but get stuck in the loop on the first element. I currently have five elements in my array (for test purposes)  (41275,41306,41334,41365,41395) and it keeps looping on 41275. Am I missing something. Many Thanks